# Workaround for two devices with the same IP address on an airgapped network which is using an unmanaged switch where DHCP isn’t an option

Tags: linux, ip, dhcp, switch, arp

So I have two IP cameras and a PC running Fedora 30 on a local network connected together using an unmanaged switch.

The two IP cameras have the same IP address by default and for reasons I won’t go into I can’t access the admin interface to give them different addresses. The switch doesn’t have DHCP (being unmanaged) so I can’t use that to change the IP addresses. I could install a DHCP server on the Fedora box but I want to avoid that.

I have tried to set up a workaround by adding static ARP table entry’s on the Fedora box for different IP addresses pointing to the MAC addresses for the two cameras in an attempt to allow me to connect to both of them at the same time. I am clearly missing some important detail as this approach isn’t working.

Is there any way for me to get this setup working without either setting up DHCP or changing the IP addresses on the cameras themselves. Hacky solutions are acceptable.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm curious why you're trying to work around the lack of admin access instead of a) getting the admin to help you out or b) resetting the admin credentials if no one knows them. Changing the camera IP addresses would be the elegant solution here, anything else would just be a workaround.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough I will explain. The cameras admin interface is protected by a username and password. I have both and therefore actually streaming from one of the cameras at a time is no issue. The problem comes when trying to login to the admin interface which doesn’t work. I looked at the JavaScript responsible and it relies on a browser extension that is bundled with the camera and can be downloaded from the login page but this is in .exe format and only supports windows. There does seem to be Mac support as well via the manufacturers website but nothing for linux.

Comment: Why not create a Windows virtual machine on your Linux system just long enough to use the admin interface to communicate with the cameras, so that you can correctly configure the IP addresses? You could also borrow a Windows laptop from a friend for an afternoon, just to complete the configuration. Once they've been set up properly, you'd never need to worry about it again. You just need a Windows system for about 30 minutes on your network, then you can completely avoid having to tinker with workarounds. Also, are you sure you can't use a web browser on your phone to set the IP addresses?

Comment: Are you sure the cameras require the extension for the whole admin interface, and not merely for watching the video stream through it?

Comment: @classhalfempty what is the make and model of the cameras?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to set up a workaround by adding static ARP table entry’s on the Fedora box for different IP addresses pointing to the MAC addresses for the two cameras in an attempt to allow me to connect to both of them at the same time. I am clearly missing some important detail as this approach isn’t working.

It isn't working because your cameras recognize that these are *the wrong IP addresses*. The cameras do receive your packets through Ethernet, but when these packets are passed up to the IP layer (in the camera's OS), they get rejected as the IP "destination address" field doesn't match any addresses that the camera 'owns'.

This method only works if the ARP entries use the cameras' real IP addresses. Which means it'll only help you choose which **one** camera you want to send packets to (instead of random), but it will not let you connect to multiple cameras at once.

> Is there any way for me to get this setup working without either setting up DHCP or changing the IP addresses on the cameras themselves. Hacky solutions are acceptable.

If the cameras use DHCP, then installing a DHCP server that issues leases *only* to these two cameras (based on their MAC addresses) would be the easiest option.

Running a DHCP server does not mean you'll be providing address leases for the entire LAN, and it also does not mean you will be acting as gateway for the devices which do obtain address leases from you.

It would also be possible to write a program which acts like a software bridge between the Ethernet interface and a virtual `tap` interface (or maybe between two `tap` interfaces, one bridged to Ethernet, the other for use by you). All it would need to do is transparently rewrite the IP address field (in both IP and ARP packets).